# How to delete the default value in a text field and type a new value using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, javascript, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my application i have to type some value in the text field. This text field contain some default value therefore first i need to delete the value and then type the new value, But neither am able to delete this value nor type a new type a new value. 
Any help would be much appreciated.
I have tried following code:

```
WebElement samount=d1.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtAmt"));
System.out.println(samount);
samount.clear();
samount.sendKeys("100");
```

I also tried this:

```
WebElement searchField=d1.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtAmt"));
System.out.println(searchField);
searchField.click();
searchField.clear();
searchField.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE );
searchField.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"));
searchField.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);
searchField.sendKeys("100");
searchField.click();
```

The following is the HTML of my page:

```
<table cellspacing="6" cellpadding="6" style="width: 100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;" colspan="2">
<br>
<table width="100%" style="text-align: center;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<td id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tdFirst" style="width:35%;"> </td>
<td style="text-align: right;">
<td style="text-align: left;">
<input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtAmt" class="txtAlpha" type="text"        style="width:100px;"       onblur="checkSender();" onkeypress="if    (WebForm_TextBoxKeyHandler(event) == false) return        false;AmountOnly();"    onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack       (\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtSenderAmt\',\'       \')', 0)" maxlength="10" value="0.00"      name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtSenderAmt">
```

Comment: what exception messages are you getting?

Comment: nothing, It's not showing any message.

Comment: Meaning it won't compile?

Comment: I dont know what is happening. I am getting following out put in the console:   Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
  2.35.3.0
  Listening on port 31936
  log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger   (org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager).
  log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

  [[InternetExplorerDriver: internet explorer on WINDOWS (9d6b5070-7fd2-4fcc-8ad9-3c8f39069d8e)] -> id:   ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtAmt]

Comment: The `clear` method should work. I think your Javascript for simulating a placeholder is getting in the way. I'd suggest using the html `placeholder` attribute

Comment: Thanks Joucks, would appreciate if you can help me on how to use "placeholde" attribute? i really hv no idea of this.

Comment: How is the placeholder set? In JavaScript? What JavaScript? Where? Your example is also invalid HTML. Please post a fully working set of HTML so we can see the elements.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks okay - I recently wrote a Selenium test driver for an ASP.Net app and I have practically the same code as your first three lines (right down to the "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_..." ;). But this means that to help you, we'll probably need more of your code -- like how "d1" is created -- because that might be where you actually have a problem.

Having said that, the first thing I notice looking at my own code is that I had to insert a wait in the following form just because trying to interact with the web page (this is all one statement, and `ffDriver` is my FirefoxDriver object):

```
(new WebDriverWait(ffDriver, 100))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("main-content")));
```

So my first instinct is that Selenium might be trying to find the element before the web page has loaded (though IIRC, you'd usually get a clearer error if so). Based on your updated question, it's possible that the presence of that JavaScript attached to the element might be slowing things down from Selenium's point of view.

Comment: Hi Emma, d1 is nothing but WebDriver. and i have tried following wait statement as well but its showing same result: WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(d1, 20);
                  wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id   ("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtAmt"))).click();

Comment: You have a stray .click() at the end of that which I don't think is correct? Also, try increasing the timeout - ASP.Net can be pretty slow to feed up its pages. My wait was set to 100 so I'd probably had trouble getting it working with lower settings.

Comment: Hi Emma, I did the changes as suggested by you but still same result. i deleted that .click and also increased the time.

Answer (score 1):

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 18);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtAmt")));
driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtAmt")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtAmt")).sendKeys("Enter-New-Text");
```